# Firefox not printing jQuery Mobile checkboxes correctly

Tags: firefox, jquery-mobile, printing

I have a checkbox that ends up being rendered in HTML as:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
  <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on"   for="contact_details_notification">Notification</label>
  <input style="background-color:#383838;" id="contact_details_notification" value="Y" type="checkbox" name="contact_details_notification">
</div>
```

Which prints fine in IE, however in FF the image (with the actual check) isn't apparently present. Might there be some easy way of tweaking this, so it prints OK?